# React Navigation Drawer display issue

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I am using React Navigation v6.6.6 on an Expo React Native project.

I've been having some weird issues with the drawer because sometimes it animates properly when I click on the hamburger icon on the header, but sometimes it does not and you have to press the screen again for it to appear.
Another issue is it doesn't open the drawer properly and I tried to tap on the backdrop but it does not close.

It would work sometimes when I try to re-open the app. But most of the time it does not toggle properly.

Also as a side note, the default screen on my Drawer Navigation is using a Tab Navigation. Would this cause an issue?

If I try to run the application through development build or Expo start, I could not see the issue from happening.

Any thoughts what could have caused this issue?